# Why can we assume the Von Neumann Algebra contains the identity?

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Consider the following fragment from "Murphy's $C^*$-algebras and operator theory":

[image: C]

The proof of theorem 4.1.11 says we can assume $id_H \in A$ in (1). I assume this to be given and from this I want to deduce that the result also holds when $id_H \notin A$.

If $id_H \notin A$, we have $$A \cong A_p$$ by remark 4.1.2 where $p$ is the unit of $A$. Moreover, the von Neumann algebra $A_p\subseteq B(p(H))$ contains $id_{p(H)}$ so by what is already known we know that $A_p$ is the closed linear span of its projections. Since we have a $*$-isomorphism $A \cong A_p$, the same also holds for $A$.

Is the above correct? I'm self-studying this and some feedback from time to time really helps me.

Comment: What are $A',\ A_p,\ u_p$?

Comment: @Berci I believe (following the quoted book) $A'$ is the commutant of $A$. $u_p$ is the restriction of $u$ to the subspace $p(H)$ and $A_p=\{u_p: u\in A\}$.

Comment: Your discussion is correct, $A$ is the same $C^*$-algebra as $A_p$, which is also a von Neumann algebra (with underlying Hilbert space $p(H)$). Further $A_p$ has a unit, so you get that you can assume that $A$ is unital if you are interested in proving any property that does not explicitly depend on the representation (ie properties that only use the $C^*$ structure, like being generated by projections).

Comment: Thanks @s.harp If you want you can make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. I'll briefly repeat your construction. Suppose $A$ is a von Neumann algebra with underlying Hilbert space $H$, it is standard that $A$ admits a unit, call the unit $p$. Note that $p$ is necessarily an orthogonal projection in $B(H)$.

For any $a\in B(H)$ define $a_p := pap$, which we understand as a map $p(H)\to p(H)$. This gives a linear map $B(H)\to B(p(H))$ and if you restrict this map to $A$ it becomes an injective $C^*$-morphism (since $p$ is the unit of $A$). It follows that the map is a $C^*$-isomorphism from $A$ to the image of $A$, call this image $A_p$.

Note that $A_p$ is a von Neumann algebra with underlying Hilbert space $p(H)$, I think the easiest method would be to check that it is a SOT closed subspace of $B(p(H))$. Further $p_p=\mathrm{id}_{p(H)}$, so $A_p$ contains the identity of the Hilbert space onto which it is represented.

---

Now if you would like to check some property of $A$ that does not explicitly reference the representation on $H$ (ie it is a property of $C^*$-algebras that are isomorphic to a von Neumann algebra rather than concrete von Neumann algebras) you can work with $A_p$ instead of $A$. For example if you can show that a von Neumann algebra containing the identity is generated by projections then this holds for $A_p$, but $A_p$ is isomorphic to $A$ and the property "is generated by projections" will be carried over by the isomorphism.

Comment: Here is another von Neumann algebra related post if you have time/are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820150/every-von-neumann-algebra-is-the-dual-of-a-banach-space-murphys-proof Thanks!